# Blocks are invisible after hosting drupal7

Tags: routes, blocks

I am facing with a problem in drupal7, I am new to drupal7 too. When I run my website in localhost everything fine, blocks and menu are visible. But after I host my website in GoDaddy, that blocks and menu are invisible, where they gone. I am also hoping someone can help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

This is the image when I call this website in localhost. We can see block and menu.
[image]

This is the image when I call after hosting this website.
[image]

Comment: I doubt, that would be paths problem. Checkout the paths you have given in blocks.

Comment: It might help if you could explain how you transfered the site.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime the issue occurs when we migrate the site. Just follow through these steps:-

1) Check the block section of the local and live site 
2) Check all blocks from the local and live
3) Now assign the blocks to the same regions in live as it is in the local setup
4) Check blocks are visible on the given region on the page or not.

Edit the blocks to set their display settings.

Answer (score 0):

You configured the block in your localsite so the data is stored in your local database.
Please take dump from your local site the import the dump into your server database.